# Rails stock ticker dashboard widget proof of concept

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m new to rails and trying to expand beyond just the standard scaffolding. I would like to build a dashboard that isn’t based on just one model but a collection of models (partials?) to view weather, the stock market, etc. Some of this data will be pulled from queries from models. Other elements will be hard coded, like the stock ticker widget which I thought I would begin with.

I began by creating a dashboard.rb file in the lib folder. I used the following code

```
class Dashboard
def self.tickertable
yahoo_client = YahooFinance::Client.new
data = yahoo_client.quotes(["BVSP", "NATU3.SA", "USDJPY=X"], [:ask, :bid, :last_trade_date])
@ask = data.ask
end
end
```

Next, I added the necessary code to the application .rb file to load the lib folder

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

I then added a _tickertable partial in a newly created views/shared folder.

```
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% Dashboard.tickertable.each do |ticker| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= ticker.name %></td>
    <td><%= ticker.symbol %></td>
    <td><%= ticker.last_trade_price %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I put this partial to an already existing view which when it loads it gives the following error:

```
undefined method `ask' for #<Array:0x6663330>
```

on the "<% Dashboard.tickertable.each do |ticker| %>" line.

What key element am I missing? I feel like I am close but clearly something is missing.

Comment: Change this `@ask = data.ask` to just `data`

Comment: So the issue is the data in your `tickertable` method is returning an array, which doesn't respond to an `ask` method, that you do when setting @ask.

Comment: HAZZAH!!! Thank You for the help. I thought I had already removed that piece. That’s what another set of eyes can do.


On a related note, am I following the right frame of thinking to do this type of dashboard? I like learning new ways to do various tasks, but I want to make sure that I am doing the right thing right not the wrong thing right.

Comment: For any others, I realized that I also needed to match up the fields in the table within the partial to what is actually requested in the array.